# Why sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't catch the exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

When it gets to `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, when I was debugging, it never got back to the line and the debug just got lost there. It never got to the catch block also. What am I missing here?

```
public void UpdateSaveAssessmentHistory()
{

    var connectionManager = new ConnectionManager(_vgp);
    var jobId = SAHelper.getNextJobID(connectionManager);
    _parameters.ExtractionType = "SaveAssessmentHistory";
    var logEntries = new List<string>();
    SAHelper.createProgressRecord(connectionManager, jobId, 0, _parameters.ExtractionType);
    var logFileName = SetUpLogFile(connectionManager, _parameters.ExtractionType, jobId);
    var sqlCommand = connectionManager.GetCommand();
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "REAL_PROP.ASSESSMENT_SAVE";
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FiscalYear", _parameters.FiscalYear));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FinalSave", _parameters.FinalSave));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RunType", _parameters.RunType));
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SaveDate", _parameters.SaveDate));
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
    try
    {
       sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       SAHelper.setCompleteforProgress(connectionManager, jobId, "COMPLETED", "SAVE ASSESSMENT HISTORY FINISHED", _parameters.ExtractionType);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SAHelper.updateProgress(connectionManager, jobId, "ERROR", e.Message, 0, _parameters.ExtractionType);
        logEntries.Add("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

        if (logEntries.Count > 0)
            SAHelper.WriteLogFile(logFileName, logEntries);
        sqlCommand.Dispose();
        connectionManager.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the query actually finished? `CommandTimeout` is `0`, meaning it's allowed to take as long as it needs.

Comment: My guess is your stored procedure is taking a super long time to execute

Comment: I would suggest running your stored proc via SQL Server Management Studio and seeing how long it takes.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: Are you opening your connection?

Comment: For starters, move your try block to handle the ENTIRE code block, not just part of it. You have a lot of code that is happening before the try block even starts. But this is impossible to debug remotely.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout. It could be because of a long stored procedure runtime, or it could be because you don't have a path to the host.

Comment: Yes, it turned out it was the procedure. It was trying to update millions of rows.